# Iphone App Development - Need help in Calendar imp

Tags: iphone

I'm working on Iphone Application Development.Making an Training Calendar APP.In this APP i have a requirement to show my Entolled Event on Calendar and add this event to calendar.

My Question is how to add this event to device Calendar.

1. Can we call iphone Device Calendar from our Code and Add this Event to user Calendar?

If it is not possible pls suggest an alternate for my Requirement.

Answer (score 0):

this is for native iphone app ,

you should check this out - contains all features of event kit

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160

for iphone web - you should consider some mobile frameworks in which not sure whether it supports device support